# How do I sort folders by actual size, instead of amount of sub-folders or files

Tags: files, directory, sort

I am pretty new with Ubuntu, so take it easy on me.

[image]

This is the "problem" (feature?) that I'm experiencing. It sorts by amount of folders and files, not by the actual file size.

I want to know much much of disk space certain folders use, not how many sub-folders/files it contains. Any way to do this? For simplicity's sake, is there any way to do this using the Unity GUI ? Or is terminal the only way?

Answer (score 11):

At least there is a GUI tool called `baobab` which you pretty sure have to install. I am sure there are more GUI tools out there. Just use your favorite search engine to find others.

On the command line, there is `ncdu` which does the job you want. Otherwise you could use plain command line tools like follows.

```
du -h --max-depth=1 <folder-to-check> | sort -h
du -h --max-depth=1 /etc/ | sort -h
```

I think all of them will output files and directories.

Comment: It seems like it was already installed on my version. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by [Thomas](https://askubuntu.com/a/873420/295286) in his answer,  you should use Disk Usage Analyzer app, aka Baobab. The default file manager, Nautilus, doesn't have a setting for displaying directory usage in bytes.

Command-line alternative to that would be `ncdu` , which you can get with `sudo apt-get install ncdu`
[image]

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score 3):

Great GUI tool called [Baobab (aka Disk Usage Analyzer)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Baobab). I am especially in love with the [interactive radial maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6oYP.png), which do a wonderful job at  showing **percent of usage per folder** and **sub-folder trees**. Takes only seconds to drill down and see where those space hogs are.

To install

```
sudo apt-get install baobab
```

To run

```
gksu baobab
```

If running on an encrypted drive, scan that particular one by going to the main page and then pressing the three lines in the upper right corner and choosing the sub-file (like home if it is encrypted).

Comment: It would be great if you could share more about why you prefer Baobab to other options that are out there!

Comment: Great suggestion Emily. I'll add some to my answer.

Comment: Nice additions to your answer—thank you for sharing, it is incredibly helpful!